# Find the hidden question and its answer

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

This is my second puzzle here. Hints and tags will be added later if required:

```
G1  B0  A1  A0  B1  A0  G1                                  
A1  E0  A1  B0  C1  B0  A1  E0  A1                          
A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  A0  B1  A0  B1  A0  A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  
A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  B0  A1  A0  A1  B0  A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  
A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  C0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  
A1  E0  A1  E0  A1  A0  A1  E0  A1                          
G1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  G1                          
H0  B1  A0  B1  H0                                          
C1  A0  H1  A0  B1  C0  A1  B0                              
H0  A1  A0  A1  C0  A1  B0  B1  A0  A1                      
A0  A1  A0  G1  B0  A1  C0  A1  A0  C1                      
A0  B1  E0  A1  E0  A1  B0  A1  B0  A1                      
A1  C0  C1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  B1  B0  A1  
H0  B1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  B0  A1              
G1  A0  D1  A0  C1  A0  B1  A0  A1                          
A1  E0  A1  A0  F1  A0  C1  C0                              
A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  A0  D1  A0  C1  A0  A1  A0  B1          
A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  B0  B1  C0  B1  C0  A1  A0              
A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  A0  C1  A0  A1  C0  A1  A0  A1  A0  A1  
A1  E0  A1  A0  C1  C0  A1  B0  A1  A0  A1  A0              
G1  A0  C1  A0  A1  A0  B1  A0  A1  A0  B1
```

I will start updating with clues every so often:

> One: A clue that will help you see three hints, to be sure that you can start looking for a solution.

Second hint:

> The number after each letter draws, you closer to the question.

Third Hint:

> You will have to work out what each Bit, represents.

Forth Hint:
**(Only view this hint if you want to get a simple break down of the first three hints)**

> Hint 1 (Letters = Numbers), Hint 2 (Draw - something Visual), Hint 3 (Numbers - on or off)

Comment: Since the numbers are all 1 and 0s I was thinking it may have something to do with binary but have no idea where to go from there.

Comment: @gabbo1092 take a look at the third hint, which I have related to your question. I will post more clues but there are stages to solve to complete this puzzle. Hints 1,2 and 3 will help you solve the first part, and also contains a clue to what is required for the next step.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So A=1, B=2 and so forth. Take as many 0's or 1's as indicated by the letter. This gives us a 21x21 grid:
>
>  `111111100101101111111`
>  `100000100111001000001`
>  `101110101101101011101`
>  `101110100101001011101`
>  `101110100010101011101`
>  `100000100000101000001`
>  `111111101010101111111`
>  `000000001101100000000`
>  `111011111111011000100`
>  `000000001010001001101`
>  `010111111100100010111`
>  `011000001000001001001`
>  `100011101010101011001`
>  `000000001101010101001`
>  `111111101111011101101`
>  `100000101111110111000`
>  `101110101111011101011`
>  `101110100110001100010`
>  `101110101110100010101`
>  `100000101110001001010`
>  `111111101110101101011`
>
>  Which looks suspiciously like a QR code:
>
>   [image]
>
>  When read on a QR code reader, the code translates to "3x14=". So I suppose the answer we're looking for is "42".

Comment: Maybe [this is the answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) that is really being sought?

Comment: @Chowzen Thanks for the edit, I was struggling with the formatting :D

Comment: The backtick can be used in spoilers `like this` for monospace formatting.

Comment: That is correct, I was going to drag out the hints for a bit longer. Now to think of my next puzzle. Also I really need to think of an original answer and something not too obvious.